# What other axioms for set theory can be written in the form: "If mathematical structures $X$ and $Y$ are equipotent, then they're isomorphic"?

Tags: set-theory, big-list

The "injective continuum function hypothesis" (ICF) is the following statement.

> **ICF (Version 0).**  For all cardinal numbers $\kappa$ and $\nu$, we have $2^\kappa = 2^\nu \rightarrow \kappa = \nu.$

I really like this axiom, because its equivalent to:

> **ICF (Version 1).** For all sets $X$ and $Y$, we have:
>
> $$|\mathcal{P}(X)| = |\mathcal{P}(Y)| \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X) \cong \mathcal{P}(Y)$$
>
> (On the left we have equality of cardinal numbers; on the right,
>   isomorphicness of posets.)

This means that, under ICF, cardinality is "more useful" than it might otherwise be, because all we need to know about $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ to tell whether or not they're isomorphic as posets is their cardinality.

> **Question.** What other potential axioms for set theory can be written in the form: "If mathematical structures $X$ and $Y$ are equipotent, then they're isomorphic"?

Comment: It isn't an axiom of set theory, but among the saturated models of a fixed first-order theory, any two that are equipotent are isomorphic.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, perhaps the axiom "every model has a saturated elementary extension" can be recast into the desired form.

Comment: Over a finite field, if two vector spaces are equipotent then they are isomorphic.